# How can thrust be generated in space which is a vacuum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, vacuum, rocket-science, propulsion

Since thrusters have no matter to push off of, how can a spacecraft generate thrust in the vacuum of space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By conservation of momentum.

When the thruster expels high velocity gas in one direction, that gas has momentum.

Since there is no *external* force acting on the system, the *total* momentum of the system (thruster and expelled gas) cannot change.

Thus, the thruster must acquire an opposing momentum such that the total momentum is unchanged.

See the Wiki article [Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation#Derivation)

Comment: So the spacecraft pushes off of the expelled gas?

Comment: Consider two masses at rest connected by a compressed spring.  If the spring is suddenly allowed to decompress, the two masses fly away from each other but the total momentum is still zero.  They "pushed off of each other".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the spacecraft pushes off of the expelled gas. That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rocket thrusters expelling gas, imagine floating in space and holding some massive object. Now imagine throwing the object as hard as you can and you will start moving the opposite way.

Comment: Also worth imagining, only to emphasize your point, if we happen to meet a big space rock around, we can certainly use it to give ourselves a push in a different direction. The big space rock may hardly budge, but we certainly will! :) (Pedantic note: assume it's not massive enough to have any appreciable gravitational pull).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you fired the thrusters in space. The rocket starts moving even if there is "no air to push against".

But the gases are accelerated in a direction opposite to that of the motion of the rocket. This requires some force on the gases. This force is provided by the rocket. Therefore, we have a force by the rocket on the gases.

And... [Newton's third law](https://www1.grc.nasa.gov/beginners-guide-to-aeronautics/newtons-laws-of-motion/) states that for every action there is an equal reaction. Therefore, the gases also apply an equal amount of force on the rocket but in the opposite direction. This is how it moves.